# Eliminating Possible Duplicate Of MDIChildren

Tags: c#, duplicates, mdichild

What is wrong with my code for preventing Duplicate of MDI Children???

```
//Create a new instance of the MDI child template form
FAnalysis fanalysis = null;
if (fanalysis != null)
{
    fanalysis.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    fanalysis.Focus();
}
else
{
    fanalysis = new FAnalysis();
    fanalysis.MdiParent = this;
    //Display the child window
    fanalysis.Show();
    changeVisible(false, false, true, true, true, true);
 }
```

Any Help Would be Appretiated... Thanks

Comment: How do you expect your local variable to not be null?

Comment: 'fanalysis = new FAnalysis();'

Comment: It's a _local_ variable.  It's different for every call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
        foreach(Form child in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (child is FAnalysis)
            {
                if (child.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
                child.BringToFront();
                return; // stop looking and exit the method
            }
        }

        // no match was found; create a new child:
        FAnalysis fanalysis = new FAnalysis();
        fanalysis.MdiParent = this;
        fanalysis.Show();
        changeVisible(false, false, true, true, true, true);
```